# plt.save within loop over writing data

Tags: python, pandas, loops, matplotlib

I have a long script which is running in a loop over different files.  I am having trouble with the save.fig command within the script.  Although it saves the figure with the individual file name the plot data is always overwritten with the data from the last loop so for example I would end up with file 1 up to file100.png but each would appear the same.

This is the plt.figure part of the script can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='radar')
ax.plot(theta+(lk<0.0)*np.pi, np.abs(lk), color='r')
ax.plot(theta+(rk<0.0)*np.pi, np.abs(rk), color='b')
ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 1)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_rlabel_position(90)
ax.set_varlabels(labels)
for label in ax.get_xticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)
plt.axvline(theta[mdpl], color='r')
plt.axvline(theta[opp_dpl], color='r')
plt.axvline(theta[mdpr], color='b')
plt.axvline(theta[opp_dpr], color='b')
idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(lk - rk)) != 0).reshape(-1) + 0
plt.plot(theta[idx], lk[idx], 'ro')
plt.savefig('{}.png'.format(name))
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

Code starts with import of CSV into dataframes, then sets output directory and name:

```
output_dir = r'C:\\path'
for name, df in zip(allfiles, listofdf):
df.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, name+ 'csv'), index=False)
```

Then loop starts

```
for df in listofdf:
```

Indent maintained through to plot section.

Comment: This is pretty unclear. There is no loop in the code. Boil it down to a [mcve] to ask about here.

Comment: what happens if you do fig.savefig instead of plt.savefig?

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my comment above. The code itself *seems* fine. So in order to find out at which point if fails, you need to create  a [mcve]. This is to be able to copy and run the code from the question, to see the same output as you get.

Comment: Unfortunately fig.savefig result in exactly the same.  Graphs 1 and 2, called graph1 and graph2 but both with graph2's data.